# Get the value for a query parameter re-actively

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

Hello I want to pass the value of my reactive data to the query parameter, but I don't know how?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'HomeRoute', query: { lang: language } }">{{
        $t("home")
      }}</router-link>
      |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import i18n from "./i18n";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      language: i18n.locale,
    };
  },
</script>
```

In this example, I want to set the value of the query parameter (lang) to be the same as i18n.local, which is store to a variable called language. I really appreciate if someone can help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your data you can make a route object and simply pass it to your **:to** property

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link :to="home_route">{{
        $t("home")
      }}</router-link>
      |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import i18n from "./i18n";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      home_route : { name: 'HomeRoute', query: { lang: i18n.locale } }
    };
  },
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It doesn't add the query to URL